# Make nulls always last when sorting

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am using underscore to sort an array. Is there a way to make nulls always last whether ascending or descending? For example:

```
[
    { name: 'a', age: 1 }, 
    { name: 'z', age: 5 }, 
    { name: '', age: 1 }, 
    { name: 'v', age: 7 }
]
```

Will produce

```
[
    { name: 'a', age: 1 }, 
    { name: 'v', age: 7 }, 
    { name: 'z', age: 5 }, 
    { name: '', age: 1 }
]
```

and descending will produce:

```
[
    { name: 'z', age: 5 }, 
    { name: 'v', age: 7 }, 
    { name: 'a', age: 1 }, 
    { name: '', age: 1 }
]
```

My real array is an array of objects so i have to pluck values out.

Comment: You can remove all the null values, why put them on the end?

Comment: I am trying to sort a property on an object. So even if a property is null the other properties are useful.

Comment: You can make a plunker so i can try to  help you?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I am trying to mimick a database "order by Name NULLS LAST"

Comment: @anguLaravel I have edited the question to make it simpler and clearer.

Comment: why not use a sort callback?

Comment: @Luke101 You edited your question but based on the old question I've added an example for you.

Comment: The condition is by the name property?

Comment: Yes, it is the name property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829205/sort-an-array-so-that-null-values-always-come-last/29829370#29829370

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to go about it but you could try something like this:

```
var arr = [{name: 'a', age: 1}, {name: 'z', age: 5}, {name: '', age: 1}, {name: 'v', age: 7 }];

_.chain(arr)
 .sortBy('name')
 //.reverse() // to sort descending
 .partition('name')
 .flatten()
 .value();
```

Result:

```
[ { name: 'a', age: 1 },
  { name: 'v', age: 7 },
  { name: 'z', age: 5 },
  { name: '', age: 1 } ]
```

Comment: This doesn't sort. -1

Comment: He didn't ask to sort.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't come out and say "SORT THIS", but that's the way i understand the question. (Also there's a comment to that effect.)

Comment: I've edited your code to match the OP's update. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @georg yeah that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with lodash, and im think underscore as this function too.

```
var users =[{name: 'a', age: 1}, {name: '', age: 4}, {name: 'z', age: 5}, {name: '', age: 1}, {name: 'v', age: 7 }];

_.sortBy(users, 'name');
```

The results will give you the null names in the beginning:

```
[{name: '', age: 1}, {name: '', age: 4}, {name: 'a', age: 1}, {name: 'z', age: 5}, {name: 'v', age: 7 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply find them after sorting and put them in the back manually. Maybe by splitting the different values in 2 arrays and then concatenating them. One of the arrays contains `non null values` and the other `the null values`