# JS sort() empty to end

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a JS sort like this:

```
records.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

This works, but some of my records are `""` or `null`.

The empty records are listed at the begin but I want them at the end.

I think there are better ways to do this than:

```
if (a == "") a = "zzzz";
```

But how can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829205/sort-an-array-so-that-null-values-always-come-last

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
records.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a === "" || a === null) return 1;
    if(b === "" || b === null) return -1;
    if(a === b) return 0;
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: care to explain with a diagram ?

Answer (score 4):

```
records.sort((a,b) => a ? b ? a.localeCompare(b) : -1 : 1);
```

A ES6 one-liner version of Eric Hotinger's answer

Answer (score 2):

Shorter way:

```
['a', '!', 'z','Z', null, undefined, '']
.sort((a, b) => !a ? 1 : (!b ? -1 : (a.localeCompare(b))) )
```