# Sort an array of numbers so that null values come last

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
var arr = [5, 25, null, 1, null, 30]
```

Using this code to sort the array from low to high, this is what's displayed as the output:

> null null 1 5 25 30

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
};
```

However, I would like the null values to be displayed last, like this:

> 1 5 25 30 null null

I had a look at [Sort an array so that null values always come last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829205/sort-an-array-so-that-null-values-always-come-last) and tried this code, however the output is still the same as the first - the null values come first:

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a===null)-(b===null) || +(a>b)||-(a<b);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first sort by not `null` and then by numbers.

```js
var arr = [5, 25, null, 1, null, 30]

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (b != null) - (a != null) || a - b;
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: How would you do it so that the array looks like [30, 25, 5, 1, null, null] ...?

Comment: @razorsyntax `arr.sort((a, b) => (b != null) - (a != null) || b - a)`

Comment: @NenadVracar how do you do it if you want to place null first??

Comment: @NenadVracar Can you explain what is happening in the first part of the return? Struggling to understand what it's doing exactly

Comment: @ThomasAllen If the a is null and b is not null then the result of the first part of the expression will be 1 because bacause `(b != null) - (a != null) = true - false = 1 - 0 = 1` and when a is not null and b is null then the result will be -1. If both a and b are not null then the result of first condition is 0 because `false - false = 0 - 0 = 0` and then the second part of the expression is called, after || and that is just `a - b`

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth You would just switch a and b in the first part of return expression like so https://jsfiddle.net/812y4j5c/1/

Comment: @NenadVracar I was able to get it working. Thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

I would use a strict comparison with `null`, because any type casting is omitted and you need for the second part only the delta of `a` and `b` for sorting.

The given example works for objects with null value or with some properties, like the given key `numberfor`, which is not available here in the array of `null` values and numbers.

```js
var array = [5, 25, null, 1, null, 30];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a === null) - (b === null) || a - b;
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Neat solution, but it's a little bit "tricky". Would certainly need a second look if I was scanning over the code.