# sorting an array of objects from smallest to biggest while throwing all null values at the end of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I wanna sort this array in ascending order based on the max ranking in the objects, but there are certain objects that have null values for ranking , I want to throw the objects with null at the end, here is what I tried but it's not working , when I am logging the first 10 ranks of the sorted array I still have undefined values

```
async function getLive(){
    let response= await fetch('https://tennisapi1.p.rapidapi.com/api/tennis/events/live', options)
    let json= await response.json()
    for(let i=0; i<10;i++){
        console.log(json.events[i].awayTeam.ranking<json.events[i].homeTeam.ranking?json.events[i].awayTeam.ranking:json.events[i].homeTeam.ranking)
    }
    json.events.sort((a, b) => {
      let x=1000000  
      let r1 = Math.min(a.awayTeam.ranking , a.homeTeam.ranking)
          
      if(r1===null){
        r1=x
      }
      x+=1
      let r2 = b.awayTeam.ranking < b.homeTeam.ranking ? b.awayTeam.ranking : b.homeTeam.ranking;
      if(r2===null){
        r2=x
      }
      x++
      return r1 - r2;
    });
    live=json.events
    console.log('-----------------------------')
    for(let i=0; i<10;i++){
        console.log(Math.min(live[i].awayTeam.ranking ,live[i].homeTeam.ranking))
    }
```

when I log here is what I get, why are the Nan values there it makes no sense

121
NaN
NaN
73
192
295
360
394
473
475

Comment: Could you please show what the fetch response is? If this is a public API, please show the `options` object so we can reproduce this.

Comment: Please also explain how the sort should work, and what you're doing with x=1000000 etc. The whole sort function can probably be simplified considerably.

Comment: or [Sort an array of numbers so that null values come last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819867/sort-an-array-of-numbers-so-that-null-values-come-last)

Answer (score 2):

There is a neat trick to make this simple. You can just coalesce `null` values as `-Infinity`!

```js
values.sort(
    (a, b) => (b ?? -Infinity) - (a ?? -Infinity)
);
```

This way, any `null` (or `undefined`) value will be replaced by the smallest possible value, hence it goes to the very end of the array.

Comment: covered in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58748962/13762301) (though pre nullish coallescing) Made  a note on that answer to update it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your data looks like, but here is an example with a simple array:

```js
const array = [1, 4, 6, 2, 7, null, 2, 5, 10, null, 3]

array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === b) return 0
  if (a === null) return 1
  if (b === null) return -1
  return a - b
})

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to first partition the array into "rated" and "unrated" items based on whether `rating` is `null`, then sort the rated items, and finally concatenating the two using the spread operator:

```js
const array = [
  {rating: 66},
  {rating: null},
  {rating: 42},
  {rating: 101},
]
const rated = array.filter(x => x.rating !== null)
const unrated = array.filter(x => x.rating === null)
rated.sort((a, b) => a.rating - b.rating)
const sorted = [...rated, ...unrated] // alternatively you could also append unrated to rated after sorting if you don't want to copy rated here
console.log(sorted)
```