# Sort observable array with 0 always being last (for both ascending and descending sort)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observable array of objects that are used to populate a table with sortable columns.

My sorting function works perfectly and is based on the following simplification:

```
self.sortTheItems = function () {
    self.items.sort(function (l, r) {
        var rslt = l === r ? 0 : l < r ? -1 : 1;
        return self.sortAscending() ? rslt : -rslt;
    });
}
```

How could this be changed to **always** place values of 0 **last** both for ascending and descending sorting?

e.g. Unsorted values:  3,1,2,2,0,1,3,0

Descending: 3,3,2,2,1,1,0,0

Ascending: 1,1,2,2,3,3,0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the main issue, sorting one value always last, has been answered many times before on stack overflow. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829205/sort-an-array-so-that-null-values-always-come-last))

To make things more interesting, you might want to explore what knockoutjs can bring to the table.

It might be nice to include a `computed` sort method and a `computed` array of sorted items so one checkbox swaps between two methods:

```js
// Wraps a sort method in a pre-check
const sortZeroesLast = sorter => (a, b) => {
  // Check both for `0`
  if (a === 0) return 1;
  if (b === 0) return -1;
  // If none is `0`, we can use our regular sorter
  return sorter(a, b);
};

// Regular sort methods
const sortAscending = (a, b) => (a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0);

const sortDescending = (a, b) => (a < b ? 1 : a > b ? -1 : 0);

const VM = function() {
  this.items = ko.observableArray([3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 5]);

  // Determine which sort function to use based on `ascending` setting
  this.ascending = ko.observable(false);

  const sorter = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    sortZeroesLast(this.ascending() ? sortAscending : sortDescending)
  );

  // Create a computed that updates when the items
  // change, or the ascending direction
  this.sortedItems = ko.pureComputed(() => this.items().sort(sorter()));

  this.input = ko.observable(0);
  this.addInput = () => {
    this.items.push(parseFloat(this.input() || 0));
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ascending">
  Ascending
</label>

<ul data-bind="foreach: sortedItems">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>

<input type="number" data-bind="value: input"><button data-bind="click: addInput">add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, very useful to see a working snippet. I will have to refactor some of the javascript due to our target browsers not supporting ES6 but I will be using your general idea in a less pretty way!

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to make it return 1 if `l` is zero - see updated script below

```js
self.items.sort(function(l, r) {
  var rslt,
    isAscending = self.sortAscending();

  if (l === r) {
    rslt = 0; // return 0 if they are equal
  } else if (l === 0) {
    if (isAscending) {
      rslt = -1; // return -1 as this is minused below to make positive 1 (moving things to the back)
    } else {
      rslt = 1; // return 1 to force to end;
    }
  } else if (l > r) {
    rslt = 1; // return 1 if l is greater than r
  } else {
    rslt = -1; // return -1 when l is less than r
  }

  return isAscending ? rslt : -rslt;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems to be on the right track but with the latest edit I am getting the order: 0,1,2,3,4 for ascending order.

Comment: Ah I forgot if it was ascending it then gets minused again, meaning we need it to be -1 for ascending and 0 - see edit above.  You'll probably be able to clean up the ifs a bit, but that is just to give you the idea

Comment: Thanks again Pete for taking the time to post a good answer. Your logic has definitely helped me but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work completely for me.

Comment: No problems, wasn't sure if it would as I don't have a platform to test on and haven't really used knockout, as long as you have found an answer, that's the main goal :)