# Sort Dom Elements By Attribute JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom

My sort function doesn't work if one of the attribute has no value: E.G:

**JS:**

```
function sortEventsByOrder(a,b) {
        const startA = parseInt($(a).data('order'));
        const startB = parseInt($(b).data('order'));    
        return startA - startB;
    }
    $('#eventList').html($('#eventList li').sort(sortEventsByOrder))
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


<ul id="eventList">
   <li data-order="5">Element 5</li>
   <li data-order="">Element 3</li>
   <li data-order="6">Element 6</li>
   <li data-order="1">Element 1</li>
   <li data-order="2">Element 2</li>
   <li data-order="4">Element 4</li>
</ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35v0v.png)
As you can see from screen shoot only sort from 6.

How can I sort the empty values to the bottom? or how to get around this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the blank data points to use max value

```js
function sortEventsByOrder(a, b) {
  const startA = parseInt($(a).data('order')) || Number.MAX_VALUE;
  const startB = parseInt($(b).data('order')) || Number.MAX_VALUE;
  return startA === startB ? 0 : startA > startB ? 1 : -1;
}

$('#eventList').append($('#eventList li').sort(sortEventsByOrder))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="eventList">
  <li data-order="5"> Element 5
  </li>
  <li data-order=""> Element 3
  </li>
  <li data-order="6"> Element 6
  </li>
  <li data-order="1"> Element 1
  </li>
  <li data-order="2"> Element 2
  </li>
  <li data-order="4"> Element 4
  </li>
</ul>
```

numbers with decimals

```js
function sortEventsByOrder(a, b) {
  var orderA = $(a).data('order')
  var orderB = $(b).data('order')
  const startA = orderA === "" ? Number.MAX_VALUE: +orderA;
  const startB = orderB === "" ? Number.MAX_VALUE: +orderB;
  return startA === startB ? 0 : startA > startB ? 1 : -1;
}

$('#eventList').append($('#eventList li').sort(sortEventsByOrder))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="eventList">
  <li data-order="5"> Element 5
  </li>
  <li data-order=""> Element 3
  </li>
  <li data-order="6"> Element 6
  </li>
  <li data-order="0"> Element 1
  </li>
  <li data-order="2.2"> Element 2
  </li>
  <li data-order="2.3"> Element 4
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good solution it also works I was also missing parseInt which in my case I was using with dynamic distance and float point which in case of 100.0 and 50.0 it would not sort as expected thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have used you solution it worked until the introduction of float pointing number however it fixed by changing to `parseFloat` but there is yet another introduction which is `0.0` it doesn't work, What could I try ? call another function in the end to move element at the top any suggestion thks

Comment: well 0 would be considered a falsely value so you would need to use https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isNaN.asp

Comment: Awesome! Super Thnks

Comment: sort from highest to the lowest, any solution?

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue swap the -1 and 1??

Comment: I surprisingly changed `startA > startB ? 1 : -1;`  to `startA < startB ? 1 : -1;`  and it worked great. I just changed `>` to  `<`. I cannot really explain how it worked but worked and sorted from largest order to the smallest, which was  what I was looking for

Comment: because you flipped the order....

Answer (score 1):

found my answer [Sort an array so that null values always come last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829205/sort-an-array-so-that-null-values-always-come-last):

```
function alphabetically(ascending) {

return function (a, b) {

// equal items sort equally
if (a === b) {
    return 0;
}
// nulls sort after anything else
else if (a === null) {
    return 1;
}
else if (b === null) {
    return -1;
}
// otherwise, if we're ascending, lowest sorts first
else if (ascending) {
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
}
// if descending, highest sorts first
else { 
    return a < b ? 1 : -1;
}

};

}

 var arr = [null, 'a', 'b', null, 'd'];

 console.log(arr.sort(alphabetically(true)));
 console.log(arr.sort(alphabetically(false)));
```

The above works for me it can be applied in DOM elements in case!