# Sorting an array that could contain undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of strings that I want to sort. The array could contain some values that are undefined. In those cases, for Ascending order, the values should come in the end, whereas in Descending order, the values should come in the beginning.

I tried

```js
var content = ["Anuja", undefined, "Ranbir", "undefined"];

content.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a == undefined) {
    a = ""
  }
  if (b == undefined) {
    b = ""
  }
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(content)
```

With this code, I get ["","", "Anuja", "Ranbir"] but my requirement is ["Anuja", "Ranbir", "", ""].

Comment: Have you tried your code? Running your code would result to `["Anuja", "Ranbir", "undefined", undefined]`.

Comment: Is `"undefined"` string also considered as `undefined`? Do you want to set the `undefined` to empty string Or you just want to sort the array?

Comment: `"undefined"` is a normal string and is not equal to `undefined` so it will be normal sorted.

Comment: Note that assigning "" to `a` or `b` in the callback does not change values in your array. You should first test your code and then come with your question.

Comment: Don't forget that uppercases sorted before lowercases, so you will return i.e. `['Alf','Peter','Tom','blue','undefined','young',undefined]`

Comment: I was typing an answer but it got locked :( 

I would propose to map your array before sorting it then you can easily sort it from a to b with undefined (now "") as the last element. 

    var content = ["Anuja", undefined, "Ranbir", "undefined"];
    // first map your array 
    content = content.map(c => {
    if(c === "undefined" || c === undefined)
    return c = "";
    
    return c
    })
    
    // then sort it
    var sorted = content.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.localeCompare(b);
    });
    
    console.log(sorted)

 see https://jsfiddle.net/45v80agd/

Comment: `var newContent = content.sort().map(val=>val==='undefined'||typeof val==='undefined'?val='':val=val)` try this , be careful using sort()

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829205/sort-an-array-so-that-null-values-always-come-last

Comment: Guys i don't care if it is an empty string or undefined. I just want it to come in the end. The whole point has been moved out of context.

Comment: you could just use sort() for that (case sensitive matters)

Comment: @ヨハンソン - the map will ignore undefined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not trivial but I found a way

```js
let content = ["Anuja", null, "Ranbir", ,null]; // note the undefined entry at index 3

// one of the few ways to detect undefined entries
// .map IGNORES undefined entries
for (let i=0;i<content.length;i++) {
  content[i] = content[i] || ""; // you may want to test for 0 here
}

const asc = (a, b) => {
  if (a === "") return 1; // can be DRY'd using *dir where dir is -1 or 1
  if (b === "") return -1;
  return a.localeCompare(b);
};
const dsc = (a, b) => {
  if (a === "") return -1;
  if (b === "") return 1;
  return b.localeCompare(a);
}


content.sort(asc);
console.log(content)
content.sort(dsc);
console.log(content)
```

Comment: However, shouldn't dsc last line be return b.localeCompare(a); ?

Comment: @Anuja Good call